# How to securely export a device (HDD)?

Tags: security, remote, storage, file-sharing, iscsi

So I have a Scientific Linux 6.3 (RHEL clone so basically the question is Redhat related) machine called "B" (with an extra "A" HDD besides the system HDD) and a notebook with SL 6.3. They are in a /24 IPv4 subnet, and can fully reach each other.

**Q**: How can I export the "A" HDD device to the notebook, so that on the notebook I could see the "A" HDD as a device /HDD/? (, and locally encrypt it using LUKS - I know this last encrypting part)

The important thing is that I need the connection to be secured (SSL?) so that no one can intercept the data that I encrypt on the notebook. **OR**: is it already encrypted via LUKS? (and an SSL connection between the notebook and the "B" machine would be just an overhead?) - extra: I also need that the "exporting of the device" must be routable over network.

**ps.: so the main question is: does encrypted communication needed between the notebook and the "B" machine or are ALL the datas on the HDD already encrypted when leaving the notebook (even LUKS pwd too??)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iSCSI Enterprise Target (iet) is what you want.

On the server end, you tell iet to take a file or block device and expose it as an iSCSI target.

On the client end, you run an iSCSI initiator.  You'll then be able to mount the target as a block device, i.e. `/dev/iscsi_target_1`

You can then take this `/dev/iscsi_target_1` and encrypt it using `cryptsetup` or `truecrypt` on your end.  Only encrypted data goes back and forth over the iSCSI session, similar to how only encrypted data would go over a SATA or other storage link in the same situation with a locally attached device.

Something a bit simpler that may work for you too: you could just create a large file on the server end and share it using NFS or samba, and use `truecrypt` to encrypt it on the client end - the encryption/decryption occurs on the system `truecrypt` is running on and no unencrypted data would be transferred.  I believe you could also mount that large file as a loopback device and use `cryptsetup` to make a LUKS volume.

Answer (score 2):

As the export data is encrypted, you don't need to encrypt the traffic. You probably don't need to authentify it either (if there's a man in the middle, your passphrase will take care of authentication as if you're not presented with the a device where the key can be decrypted with your passphrase, it will just fail).

A simple solution and that works over internet to export a block device is using nbd (network block device). Run a nbd-server on the *exported* and nbd-client where you want to use it. nbd devices can also be partitionned (`modprobe nbd max_part=16`).

nbd is over one TCP connection, so you can also encapsulate it in ssh or openssl (using socat), or SOCKS or a HTTP proxy...

Comment: looks good, I will try it, ty!